# Construct Microsoft Graph URL to gain access to inbox and users list

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I need to construct a Microsoft Graph URL so that when an admin clicks on the authorize button my application can read the user's list and inbox. I was successful in reading my own users list and their inboxes but when I tried to read the users list and inboxes of different third-party accounts after admin approval, I was getting an error. The URL which I created for authorization is given below

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my_tenant_id>/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id=<my_client_id>&state=<state_id>&redirect_uri=<some_url>&scope=Directory.Read.All%20Mail.ReadWrite%20User.Read.All%20offline_access
```

The error i am getting when an third party admin tries to authorize it

> User account '{EmailHidden}' does not exist in tenant 'Company' and
> cannot access the application ''() in that tenant.
> The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first.
> Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory
> user account

Comment: What error was reported?

Comment: added the error.

Comment: You need to add this account to the tenant as a guest account:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: @CarlZhao I saw a different authorization mechanism, where we just have to authorize from admin account and give them permission and they can read our emails and user's information. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What you said is only feasible for users in the tenant, but obviously not feasible for third-party accounts, because the third-party accounts are not in the tenant.